# SQL Query Not quite working - Unengaged Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data, sql-studio

I'm using SSMS and trying to identify contacts that have received 10 or more emails in the past 1 year and have not clicked or open any. When I run the query, some contacts fit the parameters, but I also see contacts in the list the opened or clicked within the last month or two

```sql
SELECT S.SubscriberKey, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM [SFMC].[dbo].[SentEvent] S
WHERE CAST(S.EVENTDATE AS DATE) > '07/25/2022'
  AND S.SubscriberKey IN (
    SELECT O.SubscriberKey
    FROM [SFMC].[dbo].[OpenEvent] O
    WHERE CAST(O.EVENTDATE AS DATE) > '08/04/2022'
  )
  AND S.SubscriberKey NOT IN (
    SELECT C.SubscriberKey
    FROM [SFMC].[dbo].[ClickEvent] C
    WHERE CAST(C.EVENTDATE AS DATE) > '08/04/2022'
  )
GROUP BY S.SubscriberKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

Comment: You are not using NOT IN for the OpenEvent table.

Comment: Thanks @VijayaKapadam. You're right!